# Why this svg is seen in browser but not in <img>?

Tags: html, svg

I have this svg dinamically generated (although staticaly stored as .svg have the same problem):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg version="1.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="hexagon" height="64"    
    width="64" viewBox="0 0 106.25 106.25" >
    <defs>
        <pattern id="tw_pattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" 
             w="3.125" width="100" height="100">
        <image xlink:href="footer_tw.png" x="6.25" y="3.125" 
            width="93.75" height="93.75"/>
    </pattern>
</defs>

    <path d="m 78.125,6.69873 25,43.30127 -25,43.30127 -50,0.006 
        -25,-43.30127 25,-43.30127 z" fill="url(#tw_pattern)" 
        style="stroke-width:6.25"/>
</svg>
```

Mime content-type set in header as `Content-Type:image/svg+xml`.

The problem is that loaded directly in the browser it looks fine but loaded as `src` attribute in `img` tag it appears as a 64x64 transparent square. Why?

Other svg files are correctly loaded in the same page.

Comment: I uploaded this as an svg file to my own server, but I don't see anything when I load it directly in the browser. http://strictquirks.nl/temp/temp.svg

Comment: Please show your `img` tag implementation.